# Show div and then hide when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(function() {
$('#toggle4').click(function() {
    $('.toggle4').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
});
```

Which works great and shows the '.toggle4' div but I want to hide it again when clicking outside/away from it.

So I added this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
        $(".toggle4").hide();  
});
```

Which works but it hides the div even when I click inside of the '.toggle4' div (it's an input box for a search form).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you click inside of `.toggle4` that click event bubbles up the DOM and triggers the event you bound to the document. You should be able to fix that with something like:

```
$('.toggle4').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Comment: Ah, this one did it. I just realized e.stopPropagation(). Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to prevent the click event from bubbling up to the document if it took place inside the toggle.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#searchField').click(function() {
    $('#toggle').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
  });
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $("#toggle").hide();
});

$("#toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchField">
<div id="toggle" class="toggle4"></div>
```

Comment: This one works too but I'm going with @j08691's answer since I just need to add this to my current code. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. He beat me to answering. I'll leave my answer up too since it has a code snippet that can be run.